# C++ How to split a string into a string and integers?

Tags: c++, string

Say I have a string x

```
string x = "Word 1 2";
```

I want to split x into a separate string for 'word' and two int variables for both '1' and '2'. Aka;

```
string z = "Word";
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
```

How could I go about doing this? I am sure there is a way to search through the string and separate is based on spaces between the different elements but I am not sure how to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: I'm absolutely positive that this is fully explained in your C++ book.

Comment: `strtok` is your friend

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok` to split the string by space and use `isdigit` to check whether it is an integer or not then you can use `atoi` to convert the string to integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and specifically its [`operator >>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

```
string x = "Word 1 2";

stringstream ss(x);
string z;
int a;
int b;
ss >> z >> a >> b;
```